# How to include a local repository that contains spaces in the Remotes field of an R package DESCRIPTION?

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

One of the dependecies for an R package I'm developing is in a local directory. Using devtools/remotes I can specify this dependency by including `Remotes: local::/path/to/the_repository` in the package DESCRIPTION.

However, the path I need to access contains spaces and I cannot figure out how to specify it correctly.

So far I've tried quoting (`local::"~/path/to/the repository"`) and escaping (`local::~/path/to/the\ repository`) but I still get

```
Error: Missing commas separating Remotes
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: This might be a better fit for the [remotes github issue page](https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/issues)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to solve this one. Perhaps backticks would work?

```r
local::`~/path/to/the repository`
```

Good luck!